# Jenkins 2.19.1 imported jobs build history showing 46yr old date. How to fix it?

Tags: jenkins, solaris, unix-timestamp

I have installed a new instance of jenkins(v2.19.1) in a Solaris machine.
After that I used Job import plugin to import the jobs from old jenkins server.
All the jobs got imported with proper configuration, but it was not having the old build history.
So to get the old build history, I deleted the builds directory and nextBuildNumber file from the job folders in new jenkins and copied it from old jenkins jobs to new jenkins jobs folder.

> > ex-
>
> ```
> cp -rfH /var/lib/jenkins-old/.jenkins/jobs/job1/builds /var/lib/jenkins-new/.jenkins/jobs/job1/
> cp -rfH /var/lib/jenkins-old/.jenkins/jobs/job1/nextBuildNumber /var/lib/jenkins-new/.jenkins/jobs/job1/
> cp -rfH /var/lib/jenkins-old/.jenkins/jobs/job1/lastStable /var/lib/jenkins-new/.jenkins/jobs/job1/
> cp -rfH /var/lib/jenkins-old/.jenkins/jobs/job1/lastSuccessful /var/lib/jenkins-new/.jenkins/jobs/job1/
> ```

After coping I am able to see all the build Histories, but now I have two issues.

1. All the build history dates which I copied are 46yrs old i.e Jan 1, 1970 1:00 AM. New jobs which I am running are have correct dates.
2. The copied files are occupying more space than they did in old jenkins.

Can somebody help me on this, did I do something wrong.
1st issue is the major problem.
Please provide me solution for the both the issues.

Comment: Try updating your Jenkins build. This was definitely a bug a year ago, and was promptly fixed.

Comment: I am using jenkins version 2.19.1. I suppose this is the latest stable version available.

Answer (score 0):

Below mentioned url is also having same issue.check this might resolve your problem.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29524

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26777

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks